# Open Sans font family causes some UI change

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am just developing a button widget with react, I used 'Open Sans' font family for html body. But without 'Open Sans' font some UI styling breaks down and when set font-family to 'Open Sans' it's working as expected. I need the CSS styling needs to be generic irrespective of font-family.

Please visit this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/usbp7.jpg to see the UI changes it makes. I made a gif and hosted.

JSX:

```
<div id="context-draggable" className={b()}>
    <button 
        onClick={() => getContextItems('center-btn',contextItems)}
        className={b('center-btn').toString()}>
            15
    </button>
    <FontIcon 
         onClick={() => getContextItems('top-left-btn',contextItems)}
         className={b('top-left-btn').toString()} 
         name='top-left' 
         size={32} 
     />
     <FontIcon 
         onClick={() => getContextItems('top-right-btn',contextItems)}
         name='top-right' 
         size={32} 
         className={b('top-right-btn').toString()} 
      />
      <FontIcon 
          onClick={() => getContextItems('bottom-left-btn',contextItems)}
          className={b('bottom-left-btn').toString()} 
          name='bottom-left' 
          size={32}  
      />
      <FontIcon 
          onClick={() => getContextItems('bottom-right-btn',contextItems)}
          name='bottom-right' 
          size={32} 
          className={b('bottom-right-btn').toString()} 
       />
       <FontIcon 
           className={b('bg-transparent').toString()} 
           name='bg-transparent' 
           size={32} 
       />
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.context-widget {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    z-index: 99999;
    cursor: grab;

    &:active {
        cursor: grabbing;
    }

    &__center-btn {
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: none;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #26231E;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #8c88884a;
        color: #A29993;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;

        &:active {
            height: 25px;
            width: 25px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    }

    &__top-left-btn,
    &__bottom-left-btn {
        color: #ff4700 !important;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;

        &:active {
            font-size: 24px !important;
        }
    }

    &__top-right-btn,
    &__bottom-right-btn {
        color: #ff4700 !important;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;

        &:active {
            font-size: 24px !important;
        }
    }

    &__top-left-btn {
        top: -4px;
        left: 0;

        &:active {
            top: -1px;
            left: 5px;
        }
    }

    &__top-right-btn {
        top: -4px;
        right: 0;

        &:active {
            top: -1px;
            right: 5px;
        }
    }

    &__bottom-left-btn {
        bottom: -6px;
        left: 0;

        &:active {
            bottom: -3px;
            left: 6px;
        }
    }

    &__bottom-right-btn {
        bottom: -6px;
        right: 0;

        &:active {
            bottom: -3px;
            right: 6px;
        }
    }

    &__bg-transparent {
        color: #0a0a0a4d !important;
        font-size: 80px !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: -16px;
        right: -5px;
    }
}
```

The above JSX and SCSS is widget component's code.

Common CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular.eot');
    src: local('Open Sans'),
        local('Open Sans'),
        url('../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#app {
    height: 100vh;
    background: #26231E;
}
```

FontIcon Component's SCSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icon_font';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('fonts/icomoon.eot');
    src: url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg'), url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype');
}

[class^="fontIcon__icon-"]:before,
[class*="fontIcon__icon-"]:before {

    font-family: 'icon_font';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    speak: none;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.fontIcon {
    color: #336699;
    font-size: 32px;

    &__icon {

        &-bottom-left:before {
            content: "\e900";
        }

        &-bottom-right:before {
            content: "\e901";
        }

        &-top-right:before {
            content: "\e902";
        }

        &-top-left:before {
            content: "\e903";
        }

        &-bg-transparent:before {
            content: "\e904";
        }
    }

    &--xnano {
        font-size: 9px;
    }

    &--nano {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    &--micro {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    &--mini {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    &--small {
        font-size: 32px;
    }

    &--medium {
        font-size: 64px;
    }

    &--large {
        font-size: 128px;
    }

    &--xlarge {
        font-size: 256px;
    }

    &--xxlarge {
        font-size: 512px;
    }

    &--disabled {
        cursor: not-allowed;
        opacity: .3;
    }
}
```

**Solution I need**: I am expecting those icons to not change its size irrespective of body tags font-family

Comment: Before the down voting begins, you might wanna show us some code

Comment: Edited with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused because whatever your default font-family is, has different font-size or font-weight or line-height.

Try putting rules in for the following:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp
```

This will ensure you have some default settings. It's also worth adding fallback font-families just in case. Something like:

```
.class {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica;
}
```

Let me know if you're still stuck.

Edit: Removed comment about updating question to include code

Comment: Would like to add in addition to this. Having re-watched your gif I really do think line-height might be the issue. It looks like your font is changing, which is then slightly bigger/smaller, and then as a result of the your absolutely positioned elements are moving by a pixel or two, causing bigger issues overall.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sorry that just now I added SCSS code of FontIcon component. I am using icomoon(https://icomoon.io/) for these icons. You can see that for these icons I am using separate font-family. So I am expecting it to not change the size due to the body tags font-family.

Comment: Thank you, line-height is what causing the problem as you said, but what I must do to solve this issue? Do I need to use line-height as normal and then style accordingly or is there some other way?

Comment: Just again noticed that even height of the element also changes when applied 'Open Sans', that is also causing the problem. I need to ensure that whatever the font-family is applied to body tag, the font icon should remain as it is.